# MySQL & PHP Insert Query Failing

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

I know there isn't enough validation in here just going through some testing.  $result always returns empty? Is my query bad?  I'm new to PHP and concatenating variables into strings is not something I have grasped full.  Going with the OOP form since I'm pretty familiar with it and the concepts.

Also, I know this code is terribly sloppy... just trying to dive right in =)
   `

```
$page = new Page();

$page->title = "Add a New Item";
$page->DisplayHeader();
$page->DisplaySidebar();

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    // make short variable names
    $name = trim($_POST['name']);
    $level = intval($_POST['level']);
    $slot = strtolower($_POST['slot']);
    $hp = intval($_POST['hp']);
    $mana = intval($_POST['mana']);
    $mvs = intval($_POST['mvs']);
    $int = intval($_POST['int']);
    $wis = intval($_POST['wis']);
    $str = intval($_POST['str']);
    $dex = intval($_POST['dex']);
    $con = intval($_POST['con']);
    $p_ac = intval($_POST['p_ac']);
    $m_ac = intval($_POST['m_ac']);
    $saves = intval($_POST['saves']);
    $hit = intval($_POST['hit']);
    $dam = intval($_POST['dam']);


    $queryOk = 1;

    if (empty($name) || empty($level) || empty($slot))
    {
        echo '<h3>Please enter all the required fields</h3>';
        $queryOk = 0;
    }

    // Instantiate database object and connect
    @ $db = new mysqli('*host*', '*user*', '*pass*', '*database*');

    // Check connection to 
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo 'Error:  Could not connect to database, try again later';
    }

    $query = "INSERT INTO items (name, level, slot, hp, mana, mvs, int, wis, str, dex, con, p_ac, m_ac, saves, hit, dam)".
    "V ALUES ('$name', $level, '$slot', $hp, $mana, $mvs, $int, $wis, $str, $dex, $con, $p_ac, $m_ac, $saves, $hit, $dam)";

    $result = $db->query($query);

    if (!$result)
    {
        echo '<h3>Error:  Item was not entered.  (Your webmaster sucks)</h3>';
    }
    else    {
        echo "<p>The items \"$name\" was successfully entered into the database.  <a href=\"equipment.php\>Back to Equipment or add another item.</a></p>";
    }

    $db->close();
}`
```

Comment: Remove the @ from $db and see if any errors are thrown.

Comment: why is there a space between V and ALUES, isn't VALUES one word? 0.o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in mysql, and you're using it as a fieldname. You'll have to escape it with backticks:

```
INSERT INTO ... (..., `int`, ...)
                      ^---^-- escapes
```

---

your query:

```
INSERT INTO items (name, level, slot, hp, mana, mvs, int, wis, str, dex, con, p_ac, m_ac, saves, hit, dam)
                                                     ^^^^--- problem here
VALUES ('$name', $level, '$slot', $hp, $mana, $mvs, $int, $wis, $str, $dex, $con, $p_ac, $m_ac, $saves, $hit, $dam)";
                                                   ^^^^^---NOT here
```

Comment: uh, no, not the value you're inesrting. the literal field name. It may mean "intelligence" to you, but to MySQL, it's "integer".

Comment: I replaced it in the values in the query like you explained?  Is that not correct?

Comment: no, it's not correct. see my edit above. Note the lack of a `$` in my original sample. e.g. I mean the name of the field you're using, not the value you're inserting into that field. **FIELD**... not variable.

Comment: @Marc B: 'It may mean "intelligence" to you, but to MySQL, it's "integer"'. I seriously laughed out loud. :)

Answer (score 2):

If the space in `V ALUES` is actually in your code that would cause your query to fail

**UPDATE**

If that isn't the cause of the error use `$mysqli->error` to see what error occurred.

```
if (!$result)
{
    echo '<h3>'$mysqli->error'  (Your webmaster sucks)</h3>';
}
```

Comment: Ah you beat my by just a few seconds! +1

Comment: Oh sorry, not sure why it's like that here, but It isn't in the source.

Comment: That space isn't in the source.  Removed the ampersand and no error were shown.

Comment: (You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'int, wis, str, dex, con, p_ac, m_ac, saves, hit, dam)VALUES ('test', 7, 'light',' at line 1 Item was not entered.

Comment: Ok, it's a SQL error. Try putting a space before the word VALUES and see what happens.